# Grothendieck universe definition without Replacement

Tags: set-theory

We have https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe
[image]
Can I change the 4th axiom about union with such formula? Is it an equivalent definition?

$\forall f. \mbox{Fun}(f)\land\mbox{dom}(f)\in U \land \mbox{ran}(f)\subseteq U \rightarrow \mbox{ran}(f)\in U$

I want to exclude parametrized union from definition of Grothendieck universe because it is defined with the use of Replacement axiom scheme.

Maybe this axiom is more appropriate?
$\forall f. \mbox{Rel}(f)\land \mbox{Fun}(f)\land\mbox{dom}(f)\in U \land \mbox{ran}(f)\subseteq U \rightarrow \mbox{ran}(f)\in U$, where

$$\mbox{Rel}(f) \Leftrightarrow \forall p\in f. \exists a. \exists b. p=\langle a,b\rangle$$
$$\mbox{Fun}(f) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \forall y_1 \forall y_2.\langle x,y_1\rangle\in f \land \langle x,y_2\rangle\in f \rightarrow y1=y2$$
$$\mbox{dom}(f)=\{x\in\bigcup\bigcup f:\exists y. \langle x,y\rangle\in f\}$$

Comment: You should include the axiom in your question, making it self-contained. And while you're at that, I'd also suggest a better title. The current one doesn't quite reflect the nature of the question, it seems to me.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, sure! Unfortuantely, I have some troubles with latex in SE so the picture is attached... Title was my first motivation, cause the union of family is defined with use of replacement schema. I previously mistakenly thought that such 1st-order axRepl was used (F[A]) in order to include use of proper functional classes, but now I think it is wrong, because every class can be restricted to A. And the main reason is definability of function. But why it is necessary?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Note that every Grothendieck universe is of the form $V_\kappa$ for some inaccessible $\kappa$ (or $\kappa=0, \omega$. Note that $V_\xi$ is the [$\xi$th Von Neumann hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe).)

Your substitute for 4 is simply the second-order replacement. Every set that satisfies conditions 1 to 3 is $V_\lambda$ for some limit ordinal $\lambda$. 
Moreover, $V_\lambda$ satisfies second-order replacement iff $\lambda$ is inaccessible.

Therefore, any set which satisfies conditions 1 to 3 of a Grothendieck universe with your condition is $V_\kappa$ for some inaccessible $\kappa$, which is a Grothendieck universe.

Comment: But I wrote this formula as a first-order axiom of Zermelo set theory(which is first-order), not second-order. Is everything ok?

Comment: @georgy_d It does not matter. You do not restrict $f$ to a first-order definable function over $V_\kappa$. Moreover, $V_\xi$ satisfies second-order separation automatically.

Comment: Oh, thanks!  Could you recommend a book which should I read to find "second-order separation" formula?

Comment: @georgy_d I do not know any specific reference to describe it, but I can express what the second-order separation is: it states if $P$ is any predicate and $x$ be a set, then $\{y\in x\mid P\}$ is also a set. (The main difference is that $P$ need not be a first-order formula, but an arbitrary subclass of the universe.)

Comment: Sorry for a lot of questions, but... What do you think was intention of "Fraenkel" to restrict axiom of replacement to first-order definable functions? What can I read about this?

Comment: @georgy_d Sorry, I do not know either. I also have heard it, but I have not heard any  philosophical backgrounds under it. It might be simply the result of embedding formal theories into first-order logic.

Comment: You mean that my formula is 2nd order replacement and it is stronger. Therefore, it should imply the 1st-order replacement. But there is a problem! How we can define f before the use of the 2nd order replacement? I think it is not possible... (Otherwise, how to define the image of a proper functional class using 2nd order Repl?) That means that there are cases when the 1st order Repl is appliable, but the 2nd is not. Does it mean that we 2nd order Repl is stronger then 1st order Repl only in presence of the 1st order Repl?

Comment: @georgy_d We need to distinguish the 'second-order replacement over $U$' and the 'second-order replacement over the universe.' The class functions over $U$ is just a set function $U\to U$ in the universe.
 We can define set functions in a usual manner, and it does not require the axiom of replacement. (We could need the axiom of replacement when we define some *specific* functions, but it is another story.)

Comment: (Side note: Not every set function requires the axiom of replacement to be defined; for example, identity functions, constant functions, intersections and unions, and so on.)